# How to check if data is updated in an observer model

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, event-observer, adminhtml, configuration

I want to check if the magento admin `->system -> configuration -> payment` methods is updated. i have hooked with `admin_system_config_changed_section_payment`. It is behaving well. In `observer.php` i want to check if any of payment methods have been updated? `hasDataChanges()` is returing always 1, `$observer->getOrigData()` is returning empty array. as below

```
Varien_Event_Observer Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [event] => Varien_Event Object
                (
                    [_observers:protected] => Varien_Event_Observer_Collection Object
                        (
                            [_observers:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [website] => 
                            [store] => 
                            [name] => admin_system_config_changed_section_payment
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [website] => 
            [store] => 
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the generic `admin_system_config_changed_section_` events are dispatched after the configuration has been saved:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')
    ->setSection($section)
    ->setWebsite($website)
    ->setStore($store)
    ->setGroups($groups)
    ->save();

// reinit configuration
Mage::getConfig()->reinit();
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_system_config_section_save_after', array(
    'website' => $website,
    'store'   => $store,
    'section' => $section
));
Mage::app()->reinitStores();

// website and store codes can be used in event implementation, so set them as well
Mage::dispatchEvent("admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}",
    array('website' => $website, 'store' => $store)
);
```

What you can do instead of observing `admin_system_config_changed_section_payment` is to observe `model_config_data_save_before` which is dispatched before the real save in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data`

Then in your observer to ensure you're observing the payment section you can add the following code:

```
$config = $observer->getObject();
if ($config->getSection() == "payment") {

}
```